# Change class of div on keypress

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the class of a div when I press the down arrow key but the class applies while I keep my finger on the button and gets removed when I press it no longer.
I want it to remain, what am I doing wrong?
This is the code:

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){
        var div = $('.searchResults').find('.results').first();
        if(!$('.searchResults').is(":hidden"))
        {
            if(e.keyCode == 40)
            {
                div.addClass('selected');
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="searchResults">
                        <a href="<? echo APP_PATH; ?>user/<? echo $user['id']; ?>"><div class="results">
                            <div style="float:left;">
                                <img  src="<? echo APP_PATH.$imgAdr['img_adr']."/thumbnail/".$imgAdr['img_name']; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div style="float:left;font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;color:black;margin-left:5px;">
                                <span class="title"><? echo $user['username']; ?></span><br/>
                                <span class="titleInfo">30 photos</span>
                            </div>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show a working fiddle? There is no code above that would ever remove the class, so something else must be removing or overriding your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`keyup()`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/), not `keydown()`, to do that.

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){ ...
```